# Telegram bot isn't printing anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I made a telegram bot with Python, but it doesn't work and does not print anything.
How can I fix the problem?

Code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
Update = Updater("78****55:AAEBv*********************qv5q49akk", use_context=True)

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Welcome to our Bot")

start_command = CommandHandler('start', start)
Update.dispatcher.add_handler(start_command)
Update.start_polling()
```

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.  Find out where it's stuck; check the values that might contribute to teh problem.

Comment: How did you deploy your bot? You use long polling so your .py script has to be continuously running.